# How to get current url along with query string in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want current url path along with its query string.

I have tried below but not getting desired output.

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname; // Returns path only
var url = window.location.href;
```

Suppose my url is http://localhost:1111/Contact/Index?text=aa.

**Note**  : query string is optional here if there is no query string then it should provide pathname only.

I want **/Contact/Index?text=aa**, TIA.

Comment: I got the answer its window.location.pathname+window.location.search.substr(1);

Comment: thanks guys for your efforts and time..

Comment: `window.location.search` will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can do

```
$(location).attr('href')
```

The location object also contains properties, like host, hash, protocol, and pathname.

Comment: So, why would you use that over `location.href`?

Comment: Because he asked for `jQuery`?

Comment: If I asked for a way to bake a cake with an industrial steel furnace, wouldn't you tell me to just use a normal oven?

Comment: No i woudn't. Because I would be curious how the cake tasted.

Comment: Rather "well done", probably.

Comment: The cake probably will be baked in light speed time. That's an advantage.

Answer (score -2):

This `window.location.pathname` will give you the path or the url.

Comment: It does not return the query string, he also wants that